# Reload knockout js view after ajax - json loaded

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js, mapping

## I am working on knockout,

### **This is static example:**

[static fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superdem/fKz2E/)

This refresh when array is changed but;

### **This is dynamic example:**

[dynamic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superdem/KU9t5/)

This is not refresh and not load in init.

json part is here;

```
      $.getJSON( "/echo/json/")
      .done(function( json ) {
         $.each(json.data.data, function(i, item){
            console.log(item.name); // json Item
            data.push(JSON.stringify(item)); // I push the json item in array
            console.log(data); //array
          })        
  })
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KU9t5/4/

your getAttachments() function should just update the contents of the observable array:

ajax call:

```
$.post( "/echo/json/", "{}")
      .done(function( json ) {
          self.attachments([]);
         $.each(data, function(i, item){
            console.log(item.name); // json Item

            self.attachments.push(item);
            console.log(self.attachments()); //array
        });        
      })
      .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
```

refresh() function:

```
self.refresh = function() {
    self.getAttachments();
  //self.attachments(self.getAttachments());
  //ko.mapping.fromJS(self.getAttachments(), self.attachments);
  console.log("attachments:" + self.attachments());

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, 
All I need "push" function